# number guessing game

Tags: probability, game-theory

Someone gets to choose a number between $1$ and $100$. I than have to try and guess by guessing a number and being told if the number is higher lower or equal. If I get the number on my first try I get $50$ on my second try $40$ and so on. Now if the other person chooses the number randomly the game is pretty clear to me. But will the other person choose the number randomly? The obvious guessing pattern is $50, 75$(or $25$) and so on. So it seems maybe the person wouldn't want to choose the numbers $50,75,25$ and maybe also not $12,13,87,88,62,63,37,38$. This logic could then be continued to deliver even more numbers that maybe shouldn't be chosen as often.

So my question is where does the equillibrium lie? Is a number chosen at random and if not what is the probability distribution and what is my guessing strategy?

Comment: This can be viewed a problem in game theory.  I have no idea how to analyze it, but I added the game-theory tag in hope of attracting the attention of someone who does.

Comment: So you can only get paid if you guess within five rounds?

Comment: yes, and if it takes 7 rounds you lose 10

Comment: @Jagol95 I **upvoted** because I like the original problem and I like your analysis.  I wonder if this problem should be attacked by a computer program.  You could (for example) **somehow** identify 5 distinct strategies, and then identify the **vulnerabilities** of each strategy; in fact your analysis constitutes the beginning of such an approach.  You could then assign probabilities to each of the 5 strategies (e.g. select each strategy with frequency 20%), and then evaluate the vulnerability of your **combined** strategy.

Comment: interesting problem!  Can someone (who has time :)) find the solution to the corresponding game for small $n$ starting from 3 and maybe we can see if there's a pattern.

Comment: I knew such an interesting/canonical sounding problem must have been thought about before.  It is called Dresher's guessing game.  The solution for small N is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080659/game-theory-what-are-best-strategies-for-high-low-game-game-details-are-below

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable to expect for a closed form solution for all N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compute the expected value if the number is chosen randomly.  You have $0.01$ chance to win $50$, $0.02$ chance to win $40$, $0.04$ chance to win $30$, $0.08$ chance to win $20$, $0.16$ chance to win $10$, $0.32$ chance to win $0$, and $0.37$ to lose $10$, giving an expected value of $2$, so you should play.

I don't see an easy way to compute the payoff if your opponent chooses the number to hurt you.  You can start with any number in the range $[36,64]$ and guarantee success in $7$ rounds.  If you follow bisection, both $1$ and $100$ are guaranteed to take the maximum number of choices, so your opponent should choose one of those.  Of course, if you recognize it, you should guess those first, despite the chance you have to go through $9$ guesses.

Comment: Say your opponent is *really* trying to hurt you. They assume you bisect and choose 1 or 100. Hence you choose 1 or 100. But they think a level up, they know you're picking 1 or 100, and they can just pick one of the numbers 6 bisections in, like 2, 3, 98, 99. But then maybe you will pick one of 2, 3, 98 ,99. Both players can keep analyzing but if you try doing this "backwards-bisection", the risk seems higher than the reward. You get very little information per guess, and by symmetry you have to guess twice (if 1 didn't work, you have to guess 100, if 2 didn't work, etc.).

Comment: And say they both keep analyzing the game one level higher, I'm curious, is there a point where both players have strategies that cannot be taken advantage of?